# How to join the two input streams of a multidevice soundcard?

Tags: alsa, jack

I have an old M-Audio Blackbox that consists of two sub-devices. If I open `qjackctl` those are advertised as `hw:Box,0` and `hw:Box,1`. Up to now I readily switched between those configurations as needed, but updating to `jack2` and it's `dbus` based control scheme has complicated things for me. `ardour3` is not able to find the `jack2` server `qjackctl` starts.

I already tried several alsa based approaches:

- [alsa ttable based approach](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Asoundrc#Joining_devices_to_make_multichannel)
- [another ttable one](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc#Virtual_multi_channel_devices)
- [using jack2 audio adapters](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1128748&page=2&p=9222621#post9222621)

**TL;DR:** how do I enable `ardour3` to see the four input streams?